# EF Core Db First - filter out tables based on schema name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have database with multiple schemas.

How do I generate Entities only for tables within specified schema?

I could specify the table names in command line `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold --tables …` but I hope there is better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--schema` option.

> --schema ...   The schemas of tables to generate entity
>   types for. To specify multiple schemas, repeat --schema for each one.
>   If this option is omitted, all schemas are included.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold